# capistrano remote requirements

Tags: deployment, capistrano

i am trying to deploy PHP app with capistrano, but i can't find what ssh commands exactly capistrano needs to have allowed on remote server.

my remote host allows this ssh channels:

- SFTP/SCP
- rsync

$ pwd called via SSH there returned nothing:

> pwd
>
> WinSCP: this is end-of-file:0

I know Capistrano needs more, but can't find what exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're able to ssh into you machine and run the "sh" command, things should be fine. There's a list of requirements here:

https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Getting-Started